# How to find deletion date for message in kafka queue

Tags: apache-kafka

I have set the retention time, but I donot the time of insert. Can we know the time when the first/oldest message in topic/partition gets deleted?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the creation time of the data files on kafka brokers, and they get deleted at this time + retention time.

For example, if you see a file dated from 12 hours ago with 20 hours retention, it'll get deleted in 8 hours.